# SyntaxError: missing : after property id in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6, syntax-error

All,

below code seems to run fine in Chrome but Firefox gives me an "missing : after property id" syntaxerror. I think there is is an issue with the syntax at the start of "navigateToDefault()". Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

```
var currentMapSelection = {
PROVINCIE: undefined,
GM_CODE: undefined,
WK_CODE: undefined,
navigateToDefault(){
    this.PROVINCIE = undefined;
    this.GM_CODE = undefined;
    this.WK_CODE = undefined;

    unhideVisited();
    xyz = [482,174.75,40];
    drawCountry('nld');
    updateLegend(colorScales.provincie)
},
navigateToProv(prov){
    this.PROVINCIE = prov;
    this.GM_CODE = undefined;
    this.WK_CODE = undefined;
    unhideVisited();
    loadProvinceData(prov)
    updateLegend(colorScales.gemeente)
},
navigateBack(){
    if (this.GM_CODE) this.navigateToProv(this.PROVINCIE);
    else this.navigateToDefault();
}
}
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: This is ES6 shorthand. If you're using an older version of Firefox, it may not support it.

Comment: Firefox version was almost pre-historic. Installed a fresh one and issue is solved! Thanks